# window.open + embedding JS into page?

Tags: javascript, html, web, popup, embed

I'm really new to coding. Using JavaScript, I'm trying to open a webpage and embed JavaScript into the opened webpage.

```
var popup = window.open("http://x.x.x.x.");
popup.document.open();
popup.document.write('<script src="http://x.x.x.x/file.js" type="text/javascript"></script>');
popup.document.close();
```

But of course this doesn't work and I'm not sure why. Would anyone be willing to recommend advice or a solution?

Comment: So, if any page could do that, it would be a huge security risk. What if my website opened facebook in a new tab and then stole your session cookie? If you explain what you're trying to achieve, maybe we can suggest alternate solutions.

Comment: Hey @Sidney, thanks for replying. Would this also not be possible with websites that aren't using TLS (like facebook.com). Is it not at all possible to embed code into webpages we invoke open?

Comment: Some folks use "userscripts" like tampermonkey to change what *they* see from a website, but it's impossible to do this for all users generically.

Comment: It *might* be possible for a website to modify a popup if the popup is the same domain. But I'm not sure. In any case, [there's a messaging API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/postMessage) so that two JavaScript documents can communicate (eg, web worker and main page or popup and opener). But do be careful of the [XY problem](http://xyproblem.info/). Do you really need two pages to communicate? Maybe there's a different way to achieve what you want.